# How can I neatly line up right-aligned check boxes with with other controls?

Tags: winforms, visual-studio, checkbox

The Visual Studio WinForms designer lets you snap together text boxes, list boxes, buttons, and so forth reasonably well.  However, a check box with CheckAlign=MiddleRight does not work quite like the others, because it has two components: the built-in label, and the check box itself.  If you line up the text with other labels, the check box is left floating and will not automatically line up.  You can turn off AutoSize and attempt to size the `CheckBox` control so the check box lines up, but this is touchy and will be thrown off by custom font sizes.

In this example, I've *almost* lined up the check box with the other controls, but not quite:

[image: Example of controls not lining up]

If I had several check boxes it would be a real headache, as with AutoSize turned off the position of the check box is relative to the end of the text, so each control has to be individually sized pixel by pixel.

What's the best way to line up check boxes with other controls?

One workaround is to not include text with the `CheckBox` and instead have a separate `Label` control.  However, by doing so you lose the ability to click on the label to toggle the check box.  On a high-resolution screen, clicking a 10x10 pixel is finicky, a poor UX experience.  You could add an `OnClick` event to the label, of course, but that seems like solving the wrong problem.

Here's an example of someone else with the same issue: in the preferences panel in Oracle SQL Developer, when there's a mix of properties the check boxes are handled with separate labels and boxes:

[image: Labels are left-aligned, text boxes and check boxes are right-aligned]

Comment: I'm trying to find one case in all my installed software where the box is placed to the right of the text, and can't find it. I would suggest to do it as all the rest have done it.

Comment: It's unlikely that a `LayoutEngine` exists that provides that level of granularity to independently set rules for the coordinates of the ballot box and text. Most `LayoutEngines` operate at the `Control` level and do not provide options for specific types of controls. You could always write your own, but it would be a lot more work than simply using a `Label`/`CheckBox` pair.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, i avoid that issue by not having the CheckBoxes aligned to the right:

[image]

[image]

rather than having the caption on the left.

[image]

[image]

Comment: That's certainly easy, but IMHO it looks terrible.  It's not bad with just one check box at the end of the list, but a longer list with several check boxes in the middle looks very strange.

Comment: Humans can handle it. On the other hand it seems strange to be able to click on the text of the check box and have it selected, but not be able to select any other field by clicking its label, even though the label and the check box text are visually close, as if of the same type.

Comment: I've been designing Windows apps for a decade and I personally always design UI like Ian suggested and my (very picky) users, project managers or QA never complained about that particular matter. Microsoft also strictly follows this pattern so why re-invent the wheel? Why struggle lining up things which aren't meant to be lined up as such? With that said I fully support Ian's answer as *a answer*.